# Trouble setting up logdna with AWS linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, logback, logdna

I am following these instructions for setting up logdna with an app running on an AWS linux server.

When I get to the command

```
sudo yum -y install logdna-agent
```

the console prints out

```
    failure: repodata/repomd.xml from logdna: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://repo.logdna.com/el6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Repository is there and accessible, https://repo.logdna.com/el6/repodata/repomd.xml maybe its yum cache issue, try

```
 yum clean all
```

and then run the command again

```
sudo yum -y install logdna-agent
```